# How to make a function in swift that addresses all UIButtons that will ever be on the ViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uibutton, uicolor

I have a longer code that spawns UIButtons onto the UIViewController every certain amount of time. But now what I am trying to do is turn their backgroundColor from a random color to UIColor.whiteColor(). Hw could I make a function that will do this to the UIButton that is clicked on but will work for every single UIButton I "spawn" in. Or is it easier to use UIViews opposed to UIButtons and take a different path? Thank you.

```
import UIKit
func randomPoint() -> CGPoint {
    let randomPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x:CGFloat(arc4random()%320),y: CGFloat(arc4random()%528))
    return randomPoint
}
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var startGameButton: UIButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

}

class ViewTwo : UIViewController {

    var timer = NSTimer()

    func randomColor() -> UIColor {
        let red = CGFloat(drand48())
        let green = CGFloat(drand48())
        let blue = CGFloat(drand48())
        return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    func spawnEnemy() {
        let enemy: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 320, y: 320, width: 25, height: 25))
        enemy.backgroundColor = randomColor()
        enemy.center = randomPoint()
        enemy.addTarget(self, action: Selector("buttonPressed"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(enemy)
    }

    // or my buttonPressed func goes but either way the app crashes when i click on one of the UIButtons

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
            sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        }

        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("spawnEnemy"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're creating your buttons to spawn them you can add a target like this:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

And then add the corresponding function to change the background color to white like this:

```
func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}
```

This will work for all buttons you spawn.

Comment: Ok, I just tried that, with the .addTarget in my button spawning function, with the buttonPressed function inside the both the viewDidLoad() override fun and the View controller. The code compiles and the simulator opens up and I click start to start, but once I click on one of the buttons, the app crashes or there is a bug. How do I solve this? Thank you? I will add my full code below.

Comment: You're just missing the colon in the action name "buttonClicked:".  You'll also want to take that function out of the viewDidLoad - it just needs to be sitting inside of your viewcontroller somewhere.  That colon should fix the crash.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I did not know about that colon thing.

Comment: No problem.  Yeah, the colon tells it that there's an argument - in this case the sender, which is the button itself.